# How to embed a Console application inside a Winforms application

Tags: c#

I'm developing an application which acts as a GUI for Minecraft Server (runs as a console Java application).

I have finished it and I also want to add a console inside the Winforms application because I want to give users more control over the program. But using streams (Process.StandardOutput) I can't simulate a console as it sometimes changes the cursor position, clears the console, etc...

So, I want to embed the process into the application somehow. The first solution I tried was removing the borders and positioning it accordingly to the form's position but unfortunately I couldn't do it.

Any working code snippets would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to change your project settings to "console application"?

Comment: I'm making a GUI application because the server is already a console application. I'm writing a GUI for the server.

Comment: You wrote *"I also want to add a console inside the Winforms application"*, this is why i commented. This way you have a winform app together with a console.

Comment: The console is not written in C#, so I can't just- OOH WAIT but whatever I just found a control and it works good, so I'm just gonna use it. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding a DOS console in a windows form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355724/embedding-a-dos-console-in-a-windows-form)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot target both subsystem `gui` and `console` in the same module ([msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/02/06/how-to-make-an-application-as-both-gui-and-console-application/)).

Instead, you could add a separate console application that uses SOAP to communicate with your application. Take a look at [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial) to achieve this task.