# How to embed C#.net console application in Web Application ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, web-applications, console-application

I know that my question is wide and I am seeking for hints and keywords that would push my research forward. I have checked the following links [Embedding a DOS console in a windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355724/embedding-a-dos-console-in-a-windows-form) and [How to embed a Console application inside a Winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340329/how-to-embed-a-console-application-inside-a-winforms-application), but all I can find is embedding console to Winform.

My objective is to first run the console which imitates the insert sql functionality. Then or synchronously, the Web Application should also start.
So I have two applications in the same solution a C#.net Console App and a Web App.

Is this possible? Help please.

Comment: What do you mean by "Web Application should also start" ? Are you talking about debugging them? After building them do you want to open run the console app and also open the browser window?

Comment: Why do you wont that ?

Comment: @Luizgrs yes exactly.

Comment: @AntonioBakula I want to use Console for inserting a record just for testing purposes

Comment: Thank you @Luizgrs, but I didnt see it before because I missed the keyword multiple startups which I was looking for afterall.. So thanks anyways.

Comment: @user2217303 why don't you insert test records from dedicated ASP.NET MVC action ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula I am just trying something different and I agree this isn't the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a Console application in the same solution as your ASP.NET Web Application project, and these two can use the same class libraries. For local testing through Visual Studio you can then add both these as Startup projects.