# How to stop close (x) event of console window if that is in use

Tags: c#, console

I have two console applications : client and server (server is self hosted wcf service).

multiple clients can connect to same server.

If user click X button of server console...and if number of clients connected to that server is > 0, it should not close.

I tried code available here [Capture console exit C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp)...and changed handler as below.

```
 private static bool Handler(CtrlType sig)
    {
        if (CanCloseServer())
        {
            exitSystem = true;
            //shutdown right away so there are no lingering threads
            //Environment.Exit(0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It still closes the window (reason I think is windows close command is uninterrupted even now). Could someone tell me how can I cancel the X event please.

Comment: Dumb question, but have you tried to catch this in the `_Closing` method?

Comment: Do we have _Closing for console app ? Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Oh, sorry, misread that. I thought it was a form you were trying to catch this in. Ignore me! Haha

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom mini-console app that doesn't have a close button to run your server program. Nice snippet is found in an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355724).

Comment: I can disable the close button instead, but what my business need is a console with X button.

Comment: What about putting a custom close button on the mini-console app?